# How to transpose multiple columns and repeat specific cells

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten

Is there a way to Split strings in a google sheet cell into multiple rows?

Example:

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>"")))&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C; C2:C<>""))), "×")))
```

[image]

Comment: I want when I delete the values in B and C, there will be results > 

car
train

If I just delete the result in column C I get the result with 6 values > 

car red
car yellow
car blue
train red
train yellow
train blue