# Split strings in a google sheet cell into multiple rows?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten

In this thread I got the correct answer, but when I delete the values in columns B and C there are no results

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73332197/how-to-transpose-multiple-columns-and-repeat-specific-cells)

Here is the google sheets formula

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
FILTER(A2:A; A2:A<>"")&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
FILTER(B2:B; B2:B<>"")))&"×"&TRANSPOSE(
FILTER(C2:C; C2:C<>""))), "×"))
```

**INPUT**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car | red | AA |
| train | yellow | BB |
|  | blue | CC |
|  |  | DD |

**OUPUT**

I want when I delete the values in B and C to have the result like below.

| A |
| --- |
| car |
| train |

If I just delete the result in column C, I get the result with 6 rows like below.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| car | red |
| car | yellow |
| car | blue |
| train | red |
| train | yellow |
| train | blue |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")&     IF(LEN(TRIM(QUERY(B2:B,,9^9))),"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")), ))&IF(LEN(TRIM(QUERY(C2:C,,9^9))),"×"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(C2:C, C2:C<>"")), )), "×"))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    =INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FLATTEN(
 FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&"+_+"&TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")))&"+_+"),"+_+")))
```

[image]